# Running pthread multiple times

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads, posix

I want a thread to run infinity times in order to execute the task described on do_work() function that it receives. However, the function is only called on the pthread_create() subroutine.

I've tried to implement the sched_yield() and the pthread_join() routines on a while loop. But it didn't work yet.

Is there any routine in which I can call the existing thread again?

```
int main (int argc, char ** argv) {

    int period;
    int priority;
    int load;
    char schedule[15];
    
    period = atoi(argv[1]);
    priority = atoi(argv[2]);
    load = atoi(argv[3]);
    strncpy(schedule,argv[4],100);
    std::cout <<  " period : " << period <<"\n priority : "<< priority << "\n load : "<< load << "\n schedule : " << schedule <<std::endl;
    

    struct sched_param param;   
    pthread_t thread;
    int rc;
    sched_setscheduler (0, SCHED_FIFO , &param);

    
    std::cout << "main() : creating thread " << std::endl;
    rc = pthread_create(&thread, NULL, do_work, (void*)load);

    if (rc) {
         std::cout << "Error:unable to create thread " << rc << std::endl;
         exit(-1);
    }
    
    int i=0;
    
    struct sigaction action;
    struct itimerval timer;
    
    while(i<10000){
        pthread_join(thread, NULL);
        sched_yield();

        i++;
    }
    pthread_exit(NULL);
    
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show a [mre]. Please clarify your problem in the question: Do you mean that your thread function does some task and returns or calls `pthread_exit` and you want it to wait for a new task instead?

Comment: not sure what you're asking. There's nothing magic about threads; the code that calls them and the code they run executes their instructions in order from top to bottom just like anything else. The thread terminates when it's done running its code. If you want to create "infinite" threads, then put `pthread_create` in a `while(1)` loop. Of course, this will exhaust resources and isn't really what you want. Maybe you want a thread routine that executes forever and doesn't return?

Comment: I wouldn't put `pthread_create` in a loop. I would rather put a loop in the thread itself.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I am sorry for my difficulty in making myself clear.

"The thread terminates when it's done running its code". I think that it means after the do_work() function ends I cannot access the thread again, right?

If so, this solves my problem. Because I was trying to do something impossible, I guess.

Coming back to rethink how to solve my problem again.

Comment: Consider using `std::thread` instead of pthreads when programming in C++.

Comment: yes. Your `while(i<10000) pthread_join(..)` makes no sense. You've created one thread, you only need to `join` on it once, not 10000 times. This very much sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Throwing threads at a problem won't magically make things faster, and in fact will make things _slower_ due to thread bookkeeping/overhead if there's no parallelization gains to be had. You'll need to describe what you're trying to do to really get some help.

Comment: @Luana Please **[edit]** your question and **add all clarification or requested information to the question**. Without seeing your `do_work` function and knowing your use case it is difficult to suggest a solution. When this function ends it will terminate the thread. If you want to it to do new work when it finished a task you must implement this yourself using some kind of communication between the worker thread and the thread that assigns the tasks.

Comment: Thread function: while(1){DoWork()}  do you need any more than that?

Answer (score 1):

You do not **call** a thread, you **create** a thread. By doing that, you specify a **start_routine** which will be called 'in' the new thread.

If you want to call repeatedly a function in a loop, then you can do the following in your **start_routine**:

```
void* start_routine(void *arg) {
    while (active) { // active: atomic global boolean value
        do_work();
    }
    // if no longer active, 
    // there could be an option to wait to become active again,
    // or exit the thread
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

`pthread_join()` is only called, if you want to **join** a thread with other thread(s). `pthread_join()` waits until the target thread has terminated. By joining the thread, all resources are given back to the system (cleanup).

Comment: Accesses to global variable `active` must be protected by a mutex or other effective synchronization mechanism -- in each thread that accesses it, including the main one -- lest undefined behavior ensue.  In this case, undefined behavior could easily take the form of the thread never recognizing changes to `active` by other threads.

Comment: @John Bollinger I've already stated in the code comment, that active has to be an 'atomic' data type. You could use for syncing a mutex, spinlock or since c++11 the atomic data types.

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to show you the code I implemented.

I was not sure about the meaning of Threads when I made this question and you helped me to understand that I cannot access the function on a thread multiple times, but I have to create it on each use.

My main objective was to find a way of calling the do_work() function on the reception of the signal SIGALRM. Thus, I just assumed the do_wordk() to be my Thread and used a sigaction struct to control the arrival of the signal.

If you guys want to test the code, it returns the execution time of the do_work() function and a message if the deadline set on your period was lost. The purpose of this work was to make an analogy with periodic threads.

To compile:
g++ teste.cpp -o exe -lrt

To run:
sudo taskset -c 0 ./exe 300 1 100000 F
sudo taskset -c 0 ./exe Period Priority Work_Load Scheduller_Policy

```
#include<signal.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<errno.h>
#include<sys/time.h>
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<string.h>


long load=1;
void deadline();
void do_work();



void wakeup(int j){
    struct itimerval aux;
    int t1, t2;
    
    getitimer( ITIMER_REAL, &aux);  //Get initial resume time
    
    t1 = aux.it_value.tv_usec;
    //std::cout << "Hello World! Thread working |Resume Time : " <<t1<< std::endl;
    
    do_work();
    
    getitimer( ITIMER_REAL, &aux);
    t2 = aux.it_value.tv_usec; //Get Final resume time
    
    std::cout << "Execution time (usec): " <<t1 - t2<< std::endl;
    
    if (t2==0){
        deadline();
    }
    return;
}

void do_work(){
    
    for ( int i = 0; i < load * 1000; i++) {
        /* do nothing , keep counting */
    }

}

void deadline() {
    std::cout << "Lost deadline!" <<  std::endl;
}

int main (int argc, char ** argv) {
    int i;
    int period;
    int priority;
    char scheduler[5];
    
    period = atoi(argv[1])*1000;
    priority = atoi(argv[2]);
    load = atoi(argv[3]);
    strcpy(scheduler, argv[4]);
    
    std::cout <<  " period : " << period <<"\n priority : "<< priority << "\n load : "<< load << "\n scheduler : " << scheduler <<std::endl;
    
    struct sched_param param;   
    param.sched_priority = priority;
    
    if (scheduler[0]=='F'){
        int r = sched_setscheduler (0, SCHED_FIFO , &param);
        if(r==-1){ perror("scheduller"); return 1;}
        std::cout <<"FIFO scheduller: "<<r<<std::endl;
        
    }else{
        int r = sched_setscheduler (0, SCHED_RR , &param);
        if(r==-1){ perror("scheduller"); return 1;}
        std::cout <<"RR scheduller: "<<r<<std::endl;
    }
    
    struct itimerval val;
    struct sigaction action;
    sigset_t mask;
    
    sigemptyset(&action.sa_mask);
    action.sa_handler = wakeup;
    action.sa_flags=SA_RESTART; 
    
    if(sigaction(SIGALRM, &action, 0)==-1){
        perror("sigaction");
        return 1;
    }
    
    
    val.it_interval.tv_sec=0;
    val.it_interval.tv_usec=period;
    val.it_value.tv_sec=0;
    val.it_value.tv_usec=period;
    
    if(setitimer(ITIMER_REAL, &val, 0)==-1){
        perror("setitimer");
        return 1;
    }
    
    if(sigwait( &mask, &i)==-1){
        perror("sigwait");
    }
    
    
    return 0;

}
```

Finally, I am really grateful for your patience in understanding my problem. This is my first question on this community and I hope I'll improve them over time. Thank you all for your answers and the effort on helping me.